# PostgreSQL, Rails 3 - how to add new foreign key in associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, model, foreign-keys, associations

I am working on the project and now I need to add a foreign key. I have these two models:class

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shops
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop, :foreign_key => 'shop_sid'
end
```

My goal is print all cities, in which is the shop. I am trying to do that this way:

```
<% @owner.shops.each do |shop| %>
  <% shop.cities.each do |city| %>
     <%=city.position%><br />
  <%end%>
<%end>

But I am getting the error
PG::Error: ERROR:  column cities.shop_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...T "cities".* FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."shop_id" = 8
```

I also tried to add the foreign key to the `cities` table:

```
alter table cities add foreign key (shop_sid) references shops (sid);
```

But got

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "shops"
```

How could I solve this problem about foreign key? Or, would be also better to update the associations?

**EDIT** - error message:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...ons"  WHERE "cities"."shop_sid" = 1034
                                                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."shop_sid" = 1034
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the foreign key on each side of the relation:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :cities, :foreign_key => 'shop_sid'
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop, :foreign_key => 'shop_sid'
end
```

Comment: I added the foreign key to both sides of the relation, the old error gone and I got this one (updated original post). What's weird - the part `"cities"."shop_sid" = 1034` is pretty wrong, because the value `1034` id the value from the column `shop_id`. What am I missing yet?

Comment: @user984621 - The error appears to be stating that your `shop_sid` field is a `varchar`. I'm also confused by your mention of a `shop_id` column. Perhaps you could post your database schema?